# Flash as3 array and loop and function

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an array:

```
var type:Array = [[[1,2,3], [1,2,3],[1,2,3]],
          [[1,2,3], [1,2,3],[1,2,3]]];
```

Then I loop it to call the a function:

```
for(var i:int = 0;i<type.length;i++) {
    addGrid(type[0][i]);
}
```

The function that I'm calling is:

```
public function addGrid(col,row:int, type:Array) {
    var newGird:GridE = new GirdE();
    newGird.col = col;
    newGird.row = row;
    newGird.type = type;
}
```

Hope it clear what i need. My Gird can be a big as the array is for the Array sample in here the Gird would be 3(Columns)x2(Rows)

Comment: Sorry, that's not clear. What's the problem?

Comment: I need to creat a GIRD form array using the addGird function where i have 3 variables that need to come from the array the col number, the row number and type number.

and in the example the array is 3x2 gird at list in my eyes.
If you look at the code you should understand the what im trying to achive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActionScript 3 [multidimensional arrays](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee9.html) may be referenced using multiple array indexes by looping your row and column.

Per your array structure, you first define rows, then columns.

This makes a lookup for cell value:

```
grid[row][col]
```

Iterating all elements could be implemented as:

```
private var grid:Array = [[[ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3 ]],
                          [[ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3 ]]];

public function loop()
{
    // for every row...
    for (var row:uint = 0; row < grid.length; row++)
    {
        // for every column...
        for (var col:uint = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++)
        {
            // your value of "1, 2, 3" in that cell can be referenced as:
            //    grid[row][col][0]  = 1
            //    grid[row][col][1]  = 2
            //    grid[row][col][2]  = 3

            // to pass row, col, and the value array to addGrid function:
            addGrid(row, col, grid[row][col]);
        }
    }
}

public function addGrid(row:int, col:int, value:Array):void
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works, i found similar answer to this myself,
i only used the calling part differently:
addGrid(gird[row][col][0], gird[row][col][1], gird[row][col][2]);